# Connecting two routers together

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I have a d-Link DIR615 router provided to me by my ISP, and a Vigor2900G router. I used to have the Vigor router as my main router, but since I upgraded my internet connection and speed, the Vigor can't reach the max speed, whereas the d-Link can. I want to connect these two routers together so that the d-Link will still serve as the primary router and the Vigor as a VPN server, but I can't seem to accomplish this. All of my devices are connected to a 16-port Dell switch.

Can someone possibly help?

Answer (score 0):

On the D-Link router, make sure that you have VPN Pass-through enabled.  Also, you may need to setup Port Forwarding on your D-link router to go to your Vigor router for the VPN ports.

Alternatively, you may just want to purchase a new router to replace your D-link that'll work for the speed that you want and have VPN capabilities built in.  The D-link DIR-330 seems to do the trick...

Comment: Another thing I found is that you might have to enable Universal Plug and Play (UPnP) on both routers. While this does increase the attack surface, it assists with compatibility between the two.